# Images crossover effect on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I would like to create an effect similar to the one on this website - http://www.esalen.org/ (please scroll down this website's homepage).

I have read on StackOverflow that this could be achieved using Parallax scrips, but haven't found anything similar.

Could anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Its right that you wont find anything on how to make such a feature, that is because its a unique feature that someone has built, you need to think about how you would make it, my suggestion is first find out how to change the color of the background when you scroll 250px down the page, then develop from there. there is no simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial at http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-cool-website-with-fancy-scrolling-effects

There's a preview button called "view the final fancy scrolling website".
Check this out, maybe it's what you are looking for.

Comment: It looks like it could be this. Thank you! Will try and come back with feedback!